# Нужна ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли тут запятая: "Огромное спасибо Маше, за проведение уроков!"?

Comment: Меня всегда интересовало: на каком основании ставят запятые где попало?)))

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет никаких оснований для постановки запятой. Это просто различные члены предложения